# Dropping NA(ish?) fields in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I find myself struggling with the `NA` fields quite a bit in Pandas. Here's an example:

```
audio =('all_audio_languages', lambda x: str(sorted({l.lower() for ls in x.dropna() for l in ls}))),
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Now, I would think that `x.dropna()` would be dropping all the NA/None/etc. types, but it seems that they are still in there. Is there a way to basically do a "hard" `dropna()` where it gets rid of everything that would (bool) evaluate to `False`?

---

Example data (though it's a large data frame so not sure if the below includes the offending data):

```
all_audio_languages
['en']
['en']
['en']
['LAS', 'en']
['LAS', 'en']
['en']
['en']
[]
```

Comment: Is possible add some sample?

Comment: @jezrael sorry it's a bit tricky -- it's a large dataframe so I'm not sure where to sample the offending data from...But let me add a quick sample.

Comment: hmmm, so function working with one column? Or multiple columns?

Comment: @jezrael -- updated. It's a dataframe across ~20 cols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need filter out `None` or `NaN` by [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.notna.html):

```
f = lambda x: str(sorted({l.lower() for ls in x.dropna() for l in ls if pd.notna(l)}))

audio = ('all_audio_languages', f)
```

Not easy test, but I try it (function was changed):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'all_audio_languages':[['Las','LAS', 'en', None], ['en','LAS']]})
print (df)
    all_audio_languages
0  [Las, LAS, en, None]
1             [en, LAS]

f = lambda x: str(sorted({l.lower() for l in x if pd.notna(l)}))

print (df['all_audio_languages'].apply(f))
0    ['en', 'las']
1    ['en', 'las']
Name: all_audio_languages, dtype: object
```

Comment: ha, there are so many operations that look so similar -- what is the difference between `.dropna()` and `.notna()` ?

Comment: @David542 - hmmm, is possible explain more `audio =('all_audio_languages', lambda x: str(sorted({l.lower() for ls in x.dropna() for l in ls}))),` ? How it working?

Comment: thanks that looks good and was helpful. Could you briefly explain the difference in your answer between `notna` and `dropna` ?

Comment: @David542 - sure, `dropna` workint with Series or column for remove missing values, `pd.notna` working for remove `NaN` or `None` from lists too (dropna for remove values from list not working, because list is not pandas object like series or df)